# Using Unichar as Lights Indicator

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to publish a report with circles indicator with the following conditions: 
-> If Coverage% is 90%-100% then it should return blue light on Coverage Indicator
-> If Coverage% is 60%-89% then it should return black light on Coverage Indicator
->  if Coverage% is less than 59% then it should return Red Light on Coverage Indicator
What I have done is created 3 different measures for each light as follows

->

```
Black Light = UNICHAR ( 9899)
```

->

```
blue light = UNICHAR ( 128309)
```

->

```
RedLight = UNICHAR ( 128308)
```

When I pull each of the above measures to the dashboard and visualize them as cards, all three measures are showing the right colours circles.

And then I created the Coverage Indicator measure using the above three measures:

```
Coverage Indicator = 
   var Coverage = [Coverage %] 
   return 
         switch (
            true(),
            isblank([Coverage %]) , blank(), 
            [coverage %] < 59.00,  [RedLight],  
            [Coverage %]  < 89.00 , [Black Light], 
            [Coverage %]  < 100.00,  [blue light]
          )
```

However, the result only shows one red circle for all numbers of Coverage.

[image]

I am not sure, how to fix these issues. I am certain than the coverage indicator measure must have some errors somewhere. Could anyone please help me with this. I am fairly new to Power BI and my knowledge of DAX language is very limited.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should compare `[coverage %]` to the fraction of 1 `[coverage %] < 0.59 ...` unless there is multiplication by 100 in the `[coverage %]` measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using conditional formatting in power bi for table/Matrix visual.

You need not to use any DAX formula. You can add required fields and balcklight column you created to table and apply conditional formatting on blacklight column based on coverage% value as shown below.

Hope this is answer you looking for. Please let me know if i can add anything further on this

[visual with conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYLY9.png)

[Conditional formatting tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xu0o.png)